# Trying to find an old book series: dark knights amputate limbs to use as magical weapons

Tags: story-identification

So I'm attempting to go back and re-read a series I first aquired about 8 years ago but am having a very difficult time finding them. I can't remember the name of any of the books or characters but I WILL write down what I can remember:

The series has a group of "dark knights" that will amputate a limb and then use the bone as a magical weapon. If I remember correctly they also encase themselves within magical armor that allows them the use of their missing limbs. The leader of this group was a prince who fell to 'the dark side'. After a while these knight's bodies start to decay.

There you have it. All I can remember. I hope someone out there can tell me something about the series that will help in tracking it down all these years later.

Comment: So, not these guys then; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zKhEw7nD9C4?

Comment: I am so, so, so glad that I'm not the only one to think of this on reading.

Comment: LOL first thing that came to mind for me as well :)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Sovereign Stone trilogy - starts with [Well of Darkness](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/28533.Well_of_Darkness?ac=1). Second-in-line to the throne, Prince Dagnarus, is ambitious and forces a young acolyte to learn evil Void magic. The mage uses this power to help the prince create a group of dark knights, called Vrykyl, who forge a knife out of their own bone. This knife has vampiric powers - it drains the life force and shares it out to all Vrykyl. All champions, whether goodly Dominion Lords or evil Vrykyl can summon protective armour to cover them. The bodies of the knights decay because the corrupting influence of the Void, and also because the books span two centuries.